# Error for list() in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting an error for below code. How to resolve it?

code:

```
a= list(set([1,2,3,4]))
print(a)
```

error:

```
TypeError    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-118-e8b21f19c16c> in <module>()
----> 1 a= list(set([1,2,3,4]))
      2 print(a)

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: did you define `list` variable anywhere in the code before? since that line works, and should work, for me.

Comment: Umm...if `print` raised the `TypeError` (since 2 in the stack trace is `print(a)`), then, somewhere in your code you did something like this: `print = [1, 2, 3]` redefining `print` to a `list`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.  Thanks for including the Traceback in your question.

Comment: Recommendation: post your full code

Comment: My code just contains above two lines . I have not used a list variable or print = [1,2,3]. Looks like list() is not working

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in your code you have defined a variable with the name "list". This hides the built-in list. The error indicates that you have assigned an instance of another class to the list variable. Or you may be using the list as a callable instead of indexing it as given below,

I think your code snippet given is not correct. I got the exact same error when I tried to use list object as a callable like below,

```
a= list(set([1,2,3,4]))
print(a(1))  # wrong! Use []
```

Comment: the problem with everything an object. I love python dearly but no language should be able to override built in functions!

Comment: @Chinny84: There are reasons to override said names. They are few and far between, but they are there.

Comment: "With Great Power Comes Great Responsibility" - :-)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams There is a difference between overriding functions as in OOP patterns but the ability to define `list` at a whim is crazy -  I good example of overriding a function, is mainly operator based. But give me an example so I can show it to my Scala homies at work..

Answer (score 2):

You're probably just have a variable "list" of type list in your local scope. For example:

```
list = []
a = list(set([1,2,3,4]))
print(a)
```

will lead to an error.
Allways remember about reproducibility. If I just copy & paste your code, it will work without any errors.